# How to make a time* range include upper bound

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've divided a day into 8 ticks of three hours each. When making this range it goes from 00:00 to 21:00, and not until 00:00 again.

```
const startDate = new Date("2021-03-14T23:00:00.000Z");
const endDate = new Date("2021-03-15T23:00:00.000Z");
const dayInThreeHourPeriods = d3.timeHour.every(3).range(startDate, endDate);

dayInThreeHourPeriods.forEach((period) => {
    console.log(`period: ${format(period, 'HH:mm')}`);
});

// outputs
// from: 00:00
// to: 21:00

// would like it to go to 24:00
```

How can I change this so that it goes to 24:00?

I want to use it for an axis:

[image]

Made a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Spindle/kfL5oh12/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended from the `.range` method, as `d3.timeHour.every` is just an alias to `interval.range`;

From [d3-time](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_range) docs:

> interval.range(start, stop[, step]) · Source
>
> Returns an array of dates representing every interval boundary after or equal to start (inclusive) **and before stop (exclusive)**. If step is specified, then every stepth boundary will be returned; for example, for the d3.timeDay interval a step of 2 will return every other day. If step is not an integer, it is floored.

---

As you've already stated in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66750279/5625547), it seems like a known issue.

Anyway, why don't use write your own logic to divide the day into 3-hours chunks? This way we don't need to rely on [d3](/questions/tagged/d3)d3's `.range` method;

```
let startDate = new Date("2021-03-14T23:00:00.000Z");
let endDate = new Date("2021-03-15T23:00:00.000Z");
var dayInThreeHourPeriods = [ startDate ];
while (endDate > startDate) {
  startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 3 * 1000));
  dayInThreeHourPeriods.push(startDate);
}
console.log(dayInThreeHourPeriods);
```

#### [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ap2ksjh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is [a known issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/issues/43).

What people tend to do is add a small time period and suddenly it's inclusive:

```
d3.range(min, max+0.001)
```

or in my case:

```
const dayInThreeHourPeriods = d3.timeHour.every(3).range(startDate, d3.timeHour.offset(endDate, 1));
```

Not ideal. Look there's a proposal to have 'rangeInclusive' which would be better already. But there is no activity on that issue.

If anyone has a better idea for the time being I'd be interested.